# Child Div Extend all across the page

Tags: html, css

Take a look at my page here:

**REMOVED**

I have a big red div taking up the entire content area.  I plan on having it stretch across the **entire** page horizontally.  I'm going to be using a carousel effect to allow my clients to sign up for an appointment one step at a time.  The div is a child of another div but I need it to be wider than it.  The center content area is a static width and is centered with `margin:auto;`.  Is there a way to make my child div as wide as the whole page while hopefully only using css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
**<div id="servicesteps"> </div>**
```

is the red div just remove it from your `<div clas="shadow" id="content">`

and put it above footer div and it should work

your final body tag will look something like this

```
    <div id="header"><div id="headpadding"></div><a href="index.html"><div class="headbutton noselect">Home</div></a><a href="services.html"><div class="headbutton noselect">Services &amp; Pricing</div></a><a href="details.html"><div class="headbutton noselect">service details</div></a><a href="get.html"><div class="headbutton noselect">Request Service</div></a><div class="headbutton noselect">Contact</div></div>
    <div id="content" clas="shadow"><div class="noselect" id="logo"></div><div id="buttonarea"><a style="display:table-cell;" href="details.html"><div class="noselect greenbutton"><span class="buttontitle">GET THE DETAILS</span>Learn about what we do before you come over!</div></a><span style="width:51px;display:table-cell;">&nbsp;</span><a style="display:table-cell;" href="get.html"><div class="noselect bluebutton "><span class="buttontitle">REQUEST SERVICE</span>Get your computer serviced in the next 48 hours!</div></a></div><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="content" -->
    <div class="fold noselect"><span style="background-color:#4F69FF;">Request Service</span></div>
    <table id="currentstatus">

    </table>

    <!-- InstanceEndEditable --></div>
<div id="servicesteps">

    </div>
<div id="footer">Dade Lamkins (DadeFixMyComputer.com) Copyright 2011.</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you would like something to stretch all the way from one side to the other. This is what I would do:

```
width: 100%;
```

That should work with your problem.

Comment: OP stated the div in question was a child div - setting it's width to 100% means it will take up the entire space of its parent.  OP wants the child div to be bigger.